# How was Sentinel Prime supposed to save humans from gravitational disturbance caused by Cybertron?

Tags: movie, transformers

In *Transformers: Dark of the Moon* movie, Sentinel Prime was going to use cheap human resources (and other natural resources) to re-build Cybertron. So, humans were important to him. Killing humans wasn't his intention. Right?

If Cybertron was successfully materialized near Earth, there'd be a big gravitational disturbance in Sol System which would alter trajectory of Earth ([Cybertron was much bigger than Earth](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tviTv.jpg). And, as it was metal world, it was denser, too. So, its mass should also be much greater than Earth). Such thing was going to kill all humans, for sure (due to instant weather changes, dynamic weather, tremendous inertial forces, Super tidal waves etc).

How was Sentinel Prime going to save humans from this crisis? I don't think Sentinel Prime failed to think about this (he was Einstein of Cybertron). Is there a technology mentioned in IDW comics, novels which could prevent this?

Or, is it a plot hole?

Comment: If Cybertron was in lockstep with Earth's orbit, it wouldn't effect the weather and climate substantially. It *would* likely effect the tidal system, however. At least from my meager understanding of astrophysics. :P

Comment: @GabeWillard Earth was going to orbit Cybertron because Cybertron was bigger and denser (means greater mass) than Earth.

Comment: In fact, astronomical bodies orbit around center of mass (collective). Any significant mass would alter center of mass which means Earth's trajectory will be changed.

Comment: Anyone capable of moving an entire planet from one side of the galaxy to the other should not find a threat in something as insignificant as gravity. Surely gravity nullification exists as a basic part of the Cybertron technology infrastructure. Planets are huge, moving them should be hard. If it isn't, there shouldn't be too much you CAN'T accomplish...

Comment: Michael Bay? Logic? Ahahahahahaha... Sorry...

Comment: After the re-building of Cybertron, would Sentinel Prime still care about the humans?

Comment: Dammit...I had almost scoured that experience from my brain.

Comment: I am on a similar wavelength with @ChetterHummin. I got the feeling that Sentinel Prime didn't care too much for the humans and was only using them as a stepping stone to restore his home, Cybertron. Once that was accomplished why care about the fate of the apes?

Comment: There is nothing in the movie to support the idea that Prime cared about the fate of the humans at all. In the episodes of the original show which the Cybertron/Earth plot is taken from, the Decepticons use the humans as slave labor but have no actual regards for their lives. Their only real concern is the energy created by the affected tides.

Comment: From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentinel_Prime#Transformers:_Dark_of_the_Moon) - "His intention is to restore Cybertron to its former glory after the war drove him mad and turned him against his ideals by siding with the Decepticons."  I've been avoiding these movies, but wouldn't "siding with the Decepticons" implicitly mean he doesn't care about humans?

Comment: @ChetterHummin The question is for "before re-building of Cybertron".. Sentinel Prime needed humans to re-build Cybertron, so human survival was important. What would happen afterward, nobody knows.

Comment: @Xantec The problem is: He couldn't use humans to restore Cybertron because all humans would be dead. An unexpected weather change affects our health badly. Think about that situation..

Comment: @SachinShekhar Actually, weather changes don't affect our health overly much in the long run. Humans live at all corners of the Earth and are constantly besieged by all forms of weather, yet we carry on.

Comment: @Xantec Humans can adapt constant weather in long run, not *dynamic* weather. Plus, who is talking about long run here. Addionally, exit from chilled AC environment to hot desert, you'll see the effects on health.

Comment: @Xantec Remember, our current distance from Sun is also key to life on Earth.

Comment: I think for something to be much larger and denser than earth, and to maintain a safe orbit (simply for its own and the sun's sake) around Sol, it would have to be somewhere closer to Jupiter than Earth.

Comment: Seems like a plot hole big enough to drive Optimus Prime through.

Comment: @Iszi - Optimus? I'd say it's big enough to drive both Metroplex and Fortress Maximus doing the foxtrot through. That's why you *never* over-analyze Bay movies, and just try to enjoy them as-is.

Comment: Cybertron isn't necessarily denser or more massive than Earth -- Earth has a liquid iron core, while the inside of Cybertron is (at least in the G1 cartoon) full of tunnels and access rooms.

Answer (score 2):

It's a problem noted in the mid-80s cartoon; *Dark of the Moon* is a combination of two stories from that show.  In the relevant cliffhanger, Optimus Prime says

> I have saved Cybertron -- only to destroy the Earth.

In the movie, Cybertron does not complete the transition to Earth-space.  So the devastation of Earth only just starts, and we never see what Sentinel Prime's plan was for using the Humans and Earth's resources before Earth was destroyed.

(My opinion:  Sentinel didn't think it through.)